# How can i add cash to shapes generated from animate cc

Tags: createjs, animate-cc

How can i add cash to shapes generated from animate cc

i don't want to miss with the file generated from Animate CC , in addtion , the file get complected quickly

regards

Comment: ca$h...you know...yolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [the official documentation](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_cache) about caching.

Comment: thanks for you time , but that mean i need to manually update the generated file , witch is not good

Comment: You could load a seperate javascript file along with the generated ones. In the seperated file you could 'connect' to the stage that is loaded in the generated one.